# IONIC2 - Show couple of components in each slide using ion-slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working with Ionic2, I want to achieve the below result with (ion-slides) but I am not be to do so.
What I can do until now is to show a specific number of components in each slide (i.e. 1 or 2 or 3 components) per slide. What I want to achieve instead is to have like 2.5 components per slide as you may see in the screenshot below (1.5 component) is showing (See the Suggested app section)

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve the same result?